# Quantify shade-off and halo effect in phase contrast microscopy

Tags: optics, microscopy

Shade-off and halo effect introduce distortion to phase contrast images. I am trying to utilize these features to write a program which could identify spherical cells from (positive) phase contrast images. Since cells are not necessarily of the same diameter, I want to figure out the theoretical intensity distribution. Could anybody give me some hints?[image: Shade-off and halo effect in phase contrast microscopy]

Comment: What is the question? Would you like a to get a physical model for the intensity?

Comment: Yes, I do want a model for the intensity.

Comment: I am not sufficiently familiar with the technique, so forgive the naive question: is there something like a calibration normal, like a slide with a sharp edge with known optical phase shift to define something like point spread function?

Comment: I am not familiar with optics, but it seems to me that a point spread function describes something like a single-slit diffraction pattern, while the phase contrast microscopy depends on the phase shift between the object (a cell in this case, with a higher refractive index) and the major background (medium in this case, with a lower refractive index).

Comment: That's why I used the phrase "something like"... the microscope response will depend on the individual optical elements and will have to be characterized in some experimental way. I am simply wondering what a practical way for that would look like? At the end of the day one will have to start with some kind of "normal", for which a response can be measured, like glass spheres or an etched step or an optical film on a slide. The question is if one can then develop a calibration model for the microscope starting with such a measurement?

Comment: I see. If one only knows the general setup of the microscope, is it possible to derive such a parameterized model that he could fit the intensity distribution shown in the figure above (which is an actual intensity distribution of a spherical cell) into? @CuriousOne

Comment: Maybe a course relationship of the kind. I was looking at the optical path in these instruments, but I can't make out a simple argument for what the transfer function should look like. All of the theory papers that I can find have, as expected, non-trivial elements and I don't know how well they match the reality of your instrument. The most complete is "Quantitative Phase Imaging" by Mustafa Mir, Basanta Bhaduri, Ru Wang, Ruoyu Zhu and Gabriel Popescu, Volume 57, July 2012, Pages 133–217 Progress in Optics.

Comment: I skimmed the reference but it did not seem to be helpful. @CuriousOne

Comment: I know... I have been looking for something closer, but I can't find anything, either. The problem, IMHO, is solvable (and has been solved, as several software products indicate), but the solution is non-trivial. Unless we have someone around here who already knows it, deriving it for you is asking a little too much from this forum, I am afraid.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't come up with more. Since nobody has voted to close, the question seems to have been accepted as appropriate and interesting. I would like to know the solution myself, actually. If you find out from other sources, feel free to post a few details and maybe a citation or two as an answer yourself, if the question should be still open.